# Invalid sizeof() struct, gap between members

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct _HEADER_IO
    {
        uint8_t field1 : 2;
        uint8_t field2 : 4;
        uint8_t field3 : 1;
        uint8_t field4 : 1;
        uint16_t field5;
        uint8_t field6;
    } HEADER_IO;
```

It's basicly a message header that will be sent over tcp. The server reads this so that it knows what data follows in the buffer. However for some reason intead of the size being 4 bytes (2+4+1+1 first byte + 2 bytes from field 5 + 1 byte field 6) the size is 6 bytes.

Looking it up in memory view it is:

```
XX AA XX XX XX AA
```

Instead of:

```
XX XX XX XX
```

Where AA are never set no matter what I do. This is a problem because I am planning for the header to be `send()` to a server and the extra bytes are included making the server interpret the header wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard C you can't help the fact that struct members can have padding inserted between them. You have to write a function to decode the data and store it in your struct before processing. This is because on some architectures unaligned memory access (reading from a pointer not aligned to, for example, 4 bytes) is very expensive and C will automatically pad your structures to avoid the cost. There's no standard way to turn the feature on or off.

For example in GCC you can add `__attribute__((packed))` after the struct definition and Visual Studio has some `#pragma` commands (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) that are also supported by GCC but beware that overall this is non-standard.

Since your comments mentioned it's a Windows program, probably it would work if you add this before the struct definition:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
```

And this after it:

```
#pragma pack(pop)
```

While it would be more portable to write code to more manually decode the header, the above approach should be faster.

Comment: What do you mean by 'write a function to decode the data and store it in your struct before processing'

Comment: I'm sorry but you confused me, where did the data array come from, and why did you shift 24 bits and not 8?

Comment: However if you're not concerned about portability, you can just set the struct packing with a compiler directive, such as a GCC or Visual C++ specialized one. Then it will work as is.

Comment: Well I am concerned about portability but this a Windows software, so I do not know how much effect packing will have on the users

Comment: Basically then if you use Visual C++ pragmas, that part of the code should be portable at least on all versions of Windows, Linux and OS X (if you double check GCC support). If you're not writing an open source library to be used with more esoteric operating systems, you might want to just use a #pragma.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a bad idea to use bitfields for things like these. Since you can't know beforehand exactly which byte the bits will end up in, and since there are padding and alignment issues.

In my opinion, it's better to "own up" to the fact that you need more control over the external representation than what C structures give you, and do it manually. You can of course keep the struct as the in-memory (internal) representation.

Basically, you would write a function like:

```
size_t header_serialize(unsigned char *buf, size_t max, const HEADER_IO *header);
```

whose job it would be to, in the memory at `buf`, build the proper byte sequence that represents `header`.

To clarify (based on comments), the intent is to read the fields from `header`, not just do e.g.

```
memcpy(buf, header, sizeof *header);  /* DON'T DO THIS! */
```

Instead, you're supposed to assemble the expected external representation, byte by byte, from the fields of `header`. That way, you always get the same external representation regardless of what the compiler does to the in-memory format of `header`.

Comment: One question, is it guaranteed that the alignment and padding of the struct will always be the same , or will it vary per system making my serialize function inconsistent

Comment: The alignment and padding will vary by system, which is why your serialize function should access the struct in the standard way reading from and writing to its members so the compiler handles it. Then while serializing, you write to a buffer of unsigned chars so you control the exact content.

Comment: Good to know thanks. +1 for this alternative, will have it in mind